# Using Android Support Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I am trying to use the support library.

I have added this dependency to the gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

And I also have downloaded it in the SDK manager

[image: Screen]

But when I try to use this Control 
[PercentRelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html) it does not work. The layout xml file does not seem to recognize it . `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout`

Any solutions please?

Comment: wasn't aware of this library. Thanks for asking question. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the dependency on your build.gradle. E.g.

```
com.android.support:percent:23.1.0
```

the `appcompat`'s dependency is not enough. You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent)

Comment: Thank you. Accepting it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

use this dependency in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
```

`PercentRelativeLayout` doesn't comes under support library.

There is nice samples also for percent support library, check [here](https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample)